# Clarification on message got from homebrew on mac os(10.11.6) while installing software

Tags: macos, homebrew, mamp-pro

When I install software with homebrew on mac os(10.11.6), I get info as follows:

> This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into
>   /usr/local.
>
> OS X provides the BSD gettext library and some software gets confused
>   if both are in the library path.
>
> Generally there are no consequences of this for you. If you build your
>   own software and it requires this formula, you'll need to add to your
>   build variables:
>
> ```
> LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib
> CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include
> ```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If/when you need to build software from source, you will need to [set the LDFLAGS and CPPFLAG options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149359/what-is-the-correct-syntax-to-add-cflags-and-ldflags-to-configure) appropriately in order for the compiler to work correctly.

The warning Homebrew is providing you here is to inform you that OS X has already provided the `gettext` tool that you installed via Homebrew. Since there are now two versions of `gettext` on your macOS system, if you need to build software from source, it's possible that the compiler could get confused about which to use at build time.

Nothing to worry about unless you need to go build software from source.